# WSO2 API Manager API authentication failure

Tags: api, security, wso2

Can anyone tell me why WSo2 API Manager does not authenticate? I have set up two WSo2 API Manager 1.8.0 instances and created an api.it is working fine as prototyped api. after it save and publish and call the api with an access token
 getting the following rsponce

```
<ams:fault xmlns:ams="http://wso2.org/apimanager/security">
<ams:code>900906</ams:code>
<ams:message>
No matching resource found in the API for the given request
</ams:message>
<ams:description>
Access failure for API: /api/stature, version: 1.0.0 with key: null
</ams:description>
</ams:fault>
```

and here is the wso2carbon.log:

```
TID[-1234] [AM] [2015-01-19 00:12:47,263] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler} - 
API authentication failure org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.oauth.OAuthAuthenticator.authenticate(OAuthAuthenticator.java:212) 
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler.handleRequest(APIAuthenticationHandler.java:94) 
org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:284) org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:83) 
org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:64) 
org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:220) 
org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:83) 
org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180) 
org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:344) 
org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:168) 
org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172) 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) 
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: How did you send the request?

Comment: sent the request through poster.

Comment: I mean, what are the parameters you have sent?

Comment: Edit API from publisher (Design wizard) and double check the availability of the resource names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
No matching resource found in the API for the given request
```

1. The above issue occurs, when your request URL is wrong and APIManager could not match that with existing published APIs.
2. If the published API configuration is not deployed properly in the gateway. You can check this, browsing to Gateway's synapse config folder/api folder.(inside/repository/deployment/server)
3. If the relevant API entries are missing at APIM DB.

Do you try with distributed setup? did you change DBs? Check above all 3 points, then you can figure out the issue quickly.

Comment: I am having the same issue with a fresh installation of WSO2. If there is a file in the synapse config folder/api folder does it mean it was "deployed properly"? What can I check in the DB to make sure things are set up properly? Thanks.

Comment: I got the same error as described in this question. While Adding new API from API publisher.In API definition I had added the resource like ```/test``` but while calling the API from the postman I was not adding the ```/test``` so I just added this and Error gone.